# Condiçao com letra em Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

eu quero so um exemplo simples de:

```
test = input('Letra: ')
```

ai se a letra digitada for ' a' (aqui que tou com problema)

```
print('exemplo')
```

eu quero que quando digite "a" apareça uma mensagem..........

Comment: Faz um `if` verificando. Você já estudou lógica de programação?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu não entendi muito bem o que você que fazer.
Você quer imprimir apenas se o caractere recebido for a letra "a"?

Se for isso, tente:

```
test = input("Letra: ")
if(test == 'a'):
    print("mensagem")
```